# Questions about implement server side and client side validation

Tags: java, ajax, validation, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm working with PlayFramework to build a registration user form that works via Ajax (it never refresh the page) and I obviously need to validate it. I'm considering two way to implement client and server side validation.

1. Send via Ajax the form data to server side validation, that save the
   user in the db if the data is valid, or send an error message to the
   frontend in case of invalid data. All of this happens via ajax
   without refresh the page. 
   **Pro**: In this way I don't implement any
   client side validation, but I get the same effect. 
   **Contro**: I'm not able to show specific
   error messages for each type of invalid data (required, min lenght,
   email format, ...)
2. Validate the form with a client side validation (jQuery Validation
   plugin), then if it's valid it sends the data to the server side
   validation. From the server side, if it's valid it registers the
   user, otherwise nothing happens (?). **Pro**: Very simple way to show
   specific error messages **Contro**: I need to implement 2 times the same
   validation logic

These are my considerations, but I don't know if they're right or if there are other better ways. What is the best way in your opinion to do this?

**The questions**:

With the first way: Is it possible from server validation send specific error messages and show them on frontend, using PlayFramework (without writing from scratch all the validation rules)?

With the second way: To implement both server and side validations I have to first validate the data with client validation then pass to the server? And with disabled javascript on browser: server side validation has to show something? (for example: notable Mediafire doesn't do that, I have to assume that for correct)

**Edit**:
Here the code I'm using to receive the form data via ajax in json format:

Controller:

```
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();      
    Form<User> userForm = User.form.bind(json);

    if(userForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest("One or more inputs are invalid");
    } else { 
       // register the user in the db
    }
```

Model (User):

```
    @Required
    public String email;

    @Required @MinLength(8) @MaxLength(16)
    public String password;

    public static Form<User> form = Form.form(User.class);
```

As it is, it returns a generic message for any invalid inputs. What I'm not able to do is: **return (with the badRequest) the specific error messages and show them under each inputs of the form**.

Comment: Questions asking what is the "best" way to achieve a goal tend to result in debate and argument, rather than a succinct correct answer. I've voted to close as "opinion based".

Comment: @DuncanJones: look at the edit, I've better explained the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to tell somebody that he tried to login with too short username, in this particular case it's enough if you'll just display an error like: *Login incorrect*. It's generally adviced to DO NOT tell the user what is the exact reason of the login fail - it prevents (a little) against the tries of brute login attempts.

How do you handle your errors depends on you, you can easily return a JSON object containing list of all errors so you can display them where you want.

For other forms (like some registration, messeging, etc) using ready to use frontend validators is good approach, as you can avoid some reduntand requests and it's just works smoother, anyway main validation should be always be done at the backend - just use frontend one as a "interesting addition to your site".

And don't worry about disabled JS - in this case you will not be able to perform even simple AJAX request ;)

**Edit**

As mentioned above you can just return a JSON object (also with list of errors) and handle it with JavaScript, although there may be many different approaches, there's one of possibilities:

```
public static Result submit() {
    Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
    ObjectNode output = Json.newObject();

    if (userForm.hasErrors()) {
        output.put("status", 400);
        output.put("errors", userForm.errorsAsJson());
        return badRequest(output);
    }

    output.put("status", 200);
    output.put("msg", "Your account was registered correctly!");
    return ok(output);

}
```

Comment: hi biesior, thanks for answer. Notice that my question is about a registration form (not login). Could you take a look at the edited first post? I've added the code I'm using and better explained what I'm not able to do. Thanks

Comment: Good, I didn't know that errorsAsJson() function. After that in JS I will have a json object to handle but I need to show each message under the inputs (not like an error wall) and this seems not so simple to do! Some advice?

Comment: using jQuery you co anything you need